# Changing image src using Controller failing under IE once src has been defined once

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I use the following code to reload an image using jQuery:

```
//Fetch image associated with new image imap.
var reportID = parseInt($('#ReportSelector').val());

$('#HistoricalChart').bind('load', function () {
    alert("loaded");
    $(this).unbind('load');
    $('#ChartLoading').hide();
    $(this).show();
}).bind('error', function () {
    $(this).unbind('error');
    $('#ChartLoading').hide();
    $('#ChartLoadingError').show();
}).attr('src', '../Chart/HistoricalChart?ReportID=' + reportID);
```

The last line of this jQuery chain indicates that I wish to change the src attribute of HistoricalChart. I use the following Controller action to do so:

```
public ActionResult HistoricalChart(int reportID)
{
    LineChart lineChart = (LineChart)Session[string.Format("HistoricalReport: {0}", reportID)];
    MemoryStream memoryStream = lineChart.ConvertToMemoryStream();
    return File(memoryStream, "image/png");
}
```

This works 100% fine under Chrome. Under IE9, however, this only works the first time. The 'loaded' alert fires every time under IE -- only the image does not change.

That is, I have a breakpoint set inside of the HistoricalChart method. The first time the HistoricalChart img has src set -- the breakpoint is hit. After this, though, the breakpoint does not get hit after calling .attr('src', ...).

Ideally I would not have to clear the src attribute, or hide the image, to resolve this issue. I do not want my image to flicker when interacting with it.

Is this a known limitation for IE? Workarounds? Or am I doing something incorrect?

Comment: Is it a cache problem? Try adding a cache buster to your URL.  `../Chart/HistoricalChart?ReportID=' + reportID + '&cachebuster=' + new Date().getTime()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are getting the cached image second time. Try adding a random number to the source url.

```
$('#HistoricalChart').bind('load', function () {
    alert("loaded");
    $(this).unbind('load');
    $('#ChartLoading').hide();
    $(this).show();
}).bind('error', function () {
    $(this).unbind('error');
    $('#ChartLoading').hide();
    $('#ChartLoadingError').show();
}).attr('src', '../Chart/HistoricalChart?ReportID=' + reportID 
                                                    + "&r=" + Math.random());
```

Comment: Except that `Math.random()` can potentially return the same value. For the cache busting value, you're better off using `new Date().getTime()`

Comment: This resolved the issue. Thank you. I will accept in 7 minutes. :)

Comment: @JuanMendes noted -- although a very small edge case, an edge case none the less. I will use Date().getTime()

Comment: @JuanMendes - `Math.random()` gives 17 digits after the decimal which is rarely going to repeat. But yes using `getTime()` is also a better idea.